# PDOStatement::execute() [pdostatement.execute]: SQLSTATE[HY093]: Invalid

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

**PDOStatement::execute() [pdostatement.execute]: SQLSTATE[HY093]: Invalid parameter number: number of bound variables does not match number of tokens in** im getting this error Why? column names are correct.

[image]

```
$baslik         = $_POST["makale_basligi"];
$icerik         = trim($_POST["makale_icerigi"]);
$meta_desc      = $_POST["makale_meta_description"];
$id             = $_POST["makale_id"];
$kategori       = $_POST["makale_kategorisi"];
$makale_link    = convertTextToLinkFormat($baslik);

$update_makale  = $db->prepare("UPDATE makale SET "
        . "makale_kategorisi        = :kategori,"
        . "makale_link_baslik       = :link,"
        . "makale_baslik            = :baslik, "
        . "makale_icerik            = :icerik, "
        . "makale_meta_description  = :desc WHERE makale_id = '".$id."' ");
$update_makale->execute(array(':kategori'=>$kategori,':link'=>$makale_link ,':baslik' =>$baslik,':icerik' =>$icerik,':desc' =>$meta_desc));
```

Comment: Why are you appending `$id` directly to the query?  The only way to be safe with prepared statements is to use them correctly.

Comment: you are right but, is problem related to it?

Comment: Possibly.  What does `$id` contain?  If it contains a `?` or a `:`, then it could be interpreted as parameter.  Or worse if I use SQL injection to break your query ;)

Comment: an integer comes from _POST

Comment: $id contains a number

Comment: If you run var_dump on the data you're providing to the query, how does it look? Also, is it giving this error always?

Comment: Also, just a hunch - what is your table's character encoding?

Comment: Another hunch here: If you replace `:desc` with `:metadesc` in your SQL and in your array of parameters, does it work?

Answer (score 0):

I dont think it is a good idea to hardcode the `$id` value and mix it with PDO parameter.
Its error prone, and Id is defined as an int in your table anyway, so why do you quote it?

Put it in the array along with the other parameters:

```
$update_makale  = $db->prepare("UPDATE makale SET "
        . "makale_kategorisi        = :kategori,"
        . "makale_link_baslik       = :link,"
        . "makale_baslik            = :baslik, "
        . "makale_icerik            = :icerik, "
        . "makale_meta_description  = :desc WHERE makale_id = :id");

$update_makale->execute(array(
    ':kategori' => $kategori,
    ':link' => $makale_link,
    ':baslik' => $baslik,
    ':icerik' => $icerik,
    ':desc' => $meta_desc,
    ':id' => $id
));
```